# Formatting on "What topics can I ask about here?" is off

Tags: bug, formatting

There's something wrong with the rendering of the second bullet list in the [Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

[image]

This might be caused by the [CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232); ♦ moderators can edit this page and make sure it looks nice again.

I've seen similar formatting issues in posts where `</ul>` is missing, like this:

- Test

Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried editing the formatting, and on my 3rd try I sussed it out.

I should have noticed first time - there was no /ul on the second list

All sorted now.

Comment: Heh, I just posted an example for how to reproduce the formatting issue :) Thanks for fixing!